# Error: "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application"

Tags: windows

I am attempting to register ACEDAO.DLL using this command line:

C:\Windows\Syswow64\regsvr32 /i acedao.dll

I get the Error: "The operating system is not presently configured to run this application"

Windows 7 and "Administrator: CMD" window

Comment: May be related: https://forums.techguy.org/threads/the-operating-system-is-not-presently-configured-to-run-this-application.500487/

Comment: If it's a 64 bit Office install then you are running the wrong regsvr32. Else, maybe something at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019235.

Comment: I have a 32 bit Office 2016 installed.

Comment: Can you point to the documentation that suggested that running `regsvr32 acedao.dll` was a sensible thing to do?

Comment: Harry, NO!  I am grasping at straws.

Comment: This download resolved my "Error 429" problem that led up to my issues with regsvr32:         http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255